# What are the structures called at the end of driveways called? Hopefully a landscaper will know

Tags: construction

I've seen them all over and can't seem to get a straight answer as to what they are called.
[image]

Some look like they can be used as gates, and some have mailboxes in them.  I've even seen them at the edges of farmer's fields.

Comment: Do you have a photo or two of the things you are talking about?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vs0uJgp
This is an example near me.

Comment: Do  you mean the brick pillars?

Comment: That's exactly it.  What are they called?

Comment: Here is another one I found.
https://imgur.com/a/z01t8fa

Comment: At the edge of a field, surely for gates, though the gates may be long in the past along with the associated fence. On driveways, mainly to impress the neighbors or whomever, with less likelihood of ever having had a gate or a fence, though the **form** comes from when gates and fences would be common at the entrance to (and the fence all around) the house area. Now it's just a vestige of a thing no longer commonly done. Thus gatepost, gate pillar, etc...even without any gate ever having been fitted.

Answer (score 2):

Gate pillars. Thats what i call mine.

Comment: Thank you.  This question is more of an annoyance to me.  I was trying to figure out why these two structures were doing at a farmer's field and when I started describing them to someone, I didn't have a name for them.

Answer (score 2):

They don't have a set name - they can be called driveway pillars, driveway columns, brick pillars, brick driveway columns or pillars, entryway brick columns or pillars, gate pillars. If you Google 'brick driveway pillars' (assuming you want brick) lots of images will come up...

Comment: From the lack of a straight answer I have gotten trying to find this, this undoubtedly is the right one, unsatisfying as it is.